# Installing Pygame on Mac into Enthought build

Tags: python, pygame, enthought

There were a number of unanswered questions on installing Pygame on a Mac but I am going to ask my specific question here and hope for an answer.

I have been having incredible difficulty installing Pygame onto my Mac.  I use the Enthought version EPD 7.3-2 32 bit and it is my default framework so if I type `python` at the terminal prompt I get:

```
$ python
Enthought Python Distribution (EPD) free version -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.3-2 (32-bit)
```

I have successfully installed additional modules to this version using Pip 1.2.1 with no issues.  I have Xcode 4.5.2 installed on my machine but I get a gcc error.

Any ideas?

Here is the trace:

```
$ pip install Pygame

Downloading/unpacking Pygame

  Running setup.py egg_info for package Pygame

    warning: no files found matching 'readme.txt'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/CVS'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/*/CVS'
Installing collected packages: Pygame
  Running setup.py install for Pygame
    building 'pygame.font' extension
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -Ddarwin -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/include/python2.7 -c src/font.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/src/font.o
    unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/folders/7p/wns1bszn1gq0zm3z2j_tdkdw0000gn/T/pip-build/Pygame/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/7p/wns1bszn1gq0zm3z2j_tdkdw0000gn/T/pip-478PM0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'pygame.font' extension

gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -Ddarwin -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/include/python2.7 -c src/font.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/src/font.o

    unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/folders/7p/wns1bszn1gq0zm3z2j_tdkdw0000gn/T/pip-build/Pygame/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/7p/wns1bszn1gq0zm3z2j_tdkdw0000gn/T/pip-478PM0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/7p/wns1bszn1gq0zm3z2j_tdkdw0000gn/T/pip-build/Pygame
Storing complete log in /Users/jchirico/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the `Command Line Tools` component of Xcode 4.5?  Launch `Xcode.app` and then select `Preferences` -> `Downloads` -> `Components` and click `Install` or `Update`.  That will install or update build tools and system headers in the traditional locations like `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Thank you!! Worked in 10 seconds.  I can NOT believe how long I was struggling over such a silly problem.

Comment: You're not alone. Apple did no one any favor by making Xcode.app default to not install the command line tools.