# Installing pygame with enthought canopy on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pygame, enthought

I'm trying to install pygame in my enthought canopy python distribution. I'm using the latest version of canopy for 64-bit Mac (Python 2.7.6), and I'm using Mavericks OS. I know that installing pygame should be possible since I managed to get pygame working with the official python 2.7.6 from the python website using the binary installation file [available here](http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip).

The first thing I tried was ensuring that canopy was my default python, and the installation file linked above, but this just re-installed pygame into the official python distribution.

Next I tried pip, which I've used to install other packages successfully (e.g., spyder). The following is what happens when I try `pip install pygame`:

> Downloading/unpacking pygame
>
> Downloading pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip (7.4Mb): 7.4Mb
>
> downloaded
>
> Running setup.py egg_info for package pygame
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
>
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Sam/build/pygame/setup.py'
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
> ```
>
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/Users/Sam/build/pygame/setup.py'

This is different to the error [reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906786/installing-pygame-on-mac-into-enthought-build), so I'm not sure at all what's going on. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution: I simply used pip to install pygame from a specific location, using `sudo pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`. Unlcear why this worked, however.

Answer (score 1):

On Yosemite and Canopy 64bit assuming you have homebrew, pygame installed fine with:

```
brew install sdl sdl_ttf sdl_image sdl_mixer
brew install hg
sudo pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

Comment: txs for posting. Your solution is the only one that worked for me. I am running OSX Yosemite in a Enthought Canopy virtual Env 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a 32 bit version of Python. PyGame doesn't run on the 64 bit builds, and OSX ships with a 64 bit build.
download from here [python2.7.3](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/python-2.7.3-macosx10.3.dmg)
then download [pygames](http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3.dmg)

Comment: This wasn't it: works fine under my 64-bit Python now.